# VSCode can now minimize to tray with a hotkey?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, autohotkey, windows-11

VSCode can now minimize to tray with a hotlkey. I can assure it, for I just did it by accident. I press some specific keys, the keys of left hand area, perhaps with ctrl or shift. This was what it happened when I pressed the hotkey: VSCode window was closed as I thought so, while it didn't acctually. Since I thought it was closed, I tried to reopen it with right clicking in the folder and choosing "Open With Code" option.

However, nothing happened after I clicked on "Open With Code", even clicking for several times. I was wondering if someting was wrong with my PC. And I tried to open another folder with VSCode, Well, it worked this time, VSCode was opened in a smaller window just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpIoX.png). I didn't realize it was because of the existence of a formerly opened VSCode window. I tried to open VSCode with right clicking in the original folder for times again, nothing happened still.

When I was just about to reboot my PC, I found the very vscode icon lying in my tray with other minimized programs. I clicked on the icon, the original window that I thought to be closed was restored. I was suprised, thinking that VSCode can be unexpectedly minimized to tray. Unfortunatelly, I didn't capture the screenshot before I clicked on the icon and it was gone with restoring of its windows. I tried to google for methods to minimize VSCode to tray, with any hotkey or command.

Well, it was not until then that I know this is still an unrealized issue on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11723).

Guys, you can try to reproduce this phenomenon with some key combinations in the left hand area and come back to comment on this thread when you are free. I did try for half an hour, sorry you tell you that I was unable to reproduce it either. All I can tell you guys is what I just experienced half an hour ago. By the way, I don't think it was caused by any extensions, for I didn't install any extensions else except C++ and python grammar extensions.

Comment: this seems to be an OS / desktop environment usage question- not a programming question

Comment: You can do this with [RBTray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray)

Answer (score -1):

In autohotkey you can do anything, just make sure you search the web for the code well before opening a thread, since you can easily find what you need without much effort

```
^Space::
    hwnd:=WinActive("A")
    WinGetTitle, Title, A
    TitleLength:=StrLen(Title)-InStr(Title, "-", , 0, 1)-1
    StringRight, Title2, Title, TitleLength

    lineOne:= "#singleinstance force" . "`n"
    lineTwo:= "hwnd:=" . hwnd . "`n"
    fileName:="ShowHide_" . Title2 . ".ahk"
    FileAppend, % lineOne . lineTwo . code, % fileName

    Run, % fileName,,, Pid
    pids.push(pid)
    DetectHiddenWindows, on
    WinWait, ahk_pid %pid%
    WinHide, ahk_id %hwnd% ; hide when new script is added
    FileDelete, % fileName
return
```